# R Time series Error

Tags: r, statistics, time-series

I am new to R and have coded the following:

```
#Dickey Fuller Test 

adf.test(Y, alternative="stationary",k=0)
adf.test(Y, alternative="explosive",k=0)

summary(lm(dPercentage ~ lpercentage, na.action=na.omit))

summary(lm(dPercentage ~ lpercentage + Trend, na.action=na.omit))
```

and receive the following error:

> summary(lm(dPercentage ~ lpercentage + Trend, na.action=na.omit))
>   Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'lpercentage' not found

Although `lpercentage` it is labelled in the data set as below

[image: See attached table]

Any help would be appreciated.

Many thanks

Saif

Comment: better check your variable name first...

Comment: Thanks a lot!, after resolving that, this now comes up                                                                                                                summary(lm(dPercentage ~ lPercentage + Trend, na.action=na.omit))
Error in model.frame.default(formula = dPercentage ~ lPercentage + Trend,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'lPercentage')